# looping through dataframe and generating random dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, random, series

I have a lookup dataframe as follows:

```
            String   Length
0            A       2
1            B       4
2            C       3
3            D       2
```

I have an input dataframe as follows:

```
   Input
0  A20
1  B1611
2  C001
3  D18
```

I want to get an output like:

```
      Output
    0  C300
    1  B2718
    2  C421
    3  A17
```

Where `B2718` is B concatenated with a random value 2718 which is a 4 digit int, and the length 4 is obtained from "Length" column of lookup.

I have written the following code:

```
def random_with_N_digits(n):
    range_start = 10**(n-1)
    range_end = (10**n)-1
    return randint(range_start, range_end)

def r_funct(lookup):
r_list = []
for index, row in lookup.iterrows():
    r_int= random_with_N_digits(row.Length)
    r_str=row.String+str(r_int)
    r_list.append(r_str)
return r_list
out_df = r_funct(lookup)
out_df = pd.DataFrame(out_df, columns=['Output'])
out_df = out_df.sample(n=in_df.size)
print(out_df)
```

But I'm unable to get the same output dataframe (out_df) on every run.

Please suggest.

Comment: Your rules are not clearly defined. Why would A20 and D18 be converted to C300 and A17, instead of A73 and D29, respectively?

Comment: @Mr.T I want the output dataframe to be in random order

Comment: But shouldn't then your sample input be "A12 B2345 C345 C456"? At the moment, it is neither connected to lookup nor input. Still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way using [`np.random.randint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) with [`pd.Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html).

Note I assume no reordering, which seems to be implied by your desired output.

```
np.random.seed(0)

def random_num(i):
    return str(np.random.randint(10**(i-1), 10**i))

df['Value'] = df['String'] + df['Length'].apply(random_num)

print(df)

  String  Length  Value
0      A       2    A42
1      B       4  B3708
2      C       3   C906
3      D       2    D13
```

Comment: I'm also looking for reordering. That is where I'm struggling. Don't want the output in the A-B-C-D order.

Comment: Can you explain the required ordering logic?

Comment: It needs to be random. No fixed logic. However, for every input value 'A20', if the output is 'B2134' then it should always be 'B2134' even when the code is re-run. PS: I've updated the code in question.

Comment: Ok, so add `np.random.seed(0)` (as per update) and your randomness is "consistent" when you rerun. You can use `sample` as per your existing code as a final step.